# Link process to connections blocked by UFW

Tags: iptables, ufw

I have an UFW setup with by default all incoming and outgoing connections blocked, and allow only to/from a wireguard interface. All services are working, but in /var/log/ufw.log, there's repeated TCP SYN attempts from my IP to multiple Google IPs(e.g https://ipinfo.io/35.232.111.17) which UFW is blocking. Other than IP and time fields, all attempts look like below:

```
Oct  2 13:42:28 System2 kernel: [ 8482.387873] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=192.168.0.137 DST=35.232.111.17 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52924 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47844 DPT=80 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Here's my ufw status and rules

```
System2 :: ~ » sudo ufw status verbose                    
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
192.168.0.0/24             ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
Anywhere on nl-ams-ss      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                                   
224.0.0.0/4/udp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on nl-ams-ss         
192.168.0.0/24             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
224.0.0.0/4/udp            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
```

Now, I didn't install anything google,so how to find out which process is trying this connection attempts ?

BTW, I'm on Mint 20.03 (based on Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: I do not see any mention of a version of Ubuntu in your question.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, updated the question.